# Uploading Multiple images in single row with comma saperated path

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to select multiple images at once and on submit click want to add in mysql with comma separated path in single row.I create code as follows

Code:-

```
if(isset($_FILES['files']))
    {
    $count = 1;
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
    {
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152)
        {
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }

        $desired_dir="user_data";
        if(empty($errors)==true)
        {
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false)
            {
                // Create directory if it does not exist
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        
            }

            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false)
            {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"user_data/".$file_name);
            }
            else
            {   
                 //rename the file if another one exist
                 $new_dir="user_data/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;
            }
        }
        else
        {
                print_r($errors);
        }

       $file_name = "user_data/".$file_name;

     echo $sql2 = "Insert statement";

    }


<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]"  multiple  placeholder="Please Upload Image" />
```

So how to achieve this task.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `foreach`, save the paths to an `array` like:

```
$paths[] = "('$path')";
```

And build your SQL outside the `foreach`, something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (path_field) values " . implode(",", $paths);
```